# Whole width on a element on flexbox navbar?

Tags: html, css

When I create navbar in flexbox layout hover is not fill whole width of a link only where text is on a element, how can i make to be whole width?

I tried several things but it wont work

Comment: Can you share here what you tried (Demo)

Comment: Do you mean you want padding on the link? You should be able to set `padding: 10px;` (or any number) on the links so their borders aren't so close to the text. If you mean the underline, the underline only shows below the text. You can use, e.g., `text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px solid black;` to create your own underline using the border which would fill the whole width of the link.

Comment: I do not mean padding, i mean when background color is on hover it's not wide enough... i can make with padding height of it but not width...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.